# Configure a DHCP server with isc that gives the clients IPs depending on the OS

Tags: ip, dhcp, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

The problem is that I cannot put a static IP or filter by mac because some clients have dual boot and use both Windows and Ubuntu, I need to be able to somehow distinguish between both OS and both with the same MAC address. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I enquire why you're trying to do this, what are you hoping to achieve there?  Assign the same user and same device different IP's depending whether they boot Windows rather than Linux?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do exactly that but do not know how.